# Product view page not open when customer log out in magento 2.3?

Tags: product, magento2.3, customer, login, view

I have a site in Magento 2.3!

My requirement is when the customer does not log in to my site so he can not see product view page.

they see only the product listing page.

and when he click product so redirect the customer login page.

So please help me asap!

Thanks.

Comment: I have added my comment below. Please use that and let me know if you are getting any issue.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/300183/82771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create events.xml file

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="customer_controller_action_predispatch_event" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ForceCustomerLoginObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ForceCustomerLoginObserver.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class ForceCustomerLoginObserver implements ObserverInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
         */
        protected $redirect;

        /**
         * Customer session
         *
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
         */
        protected $_customerSession;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect

        ) {

            $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
            $this->redirect = $redirect;

        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();

$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

            if($actionName == 'catalog_product_view')
            {
                if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                    $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**After that don't forgot to clean cache !!**

Comment: Did you means create a new module in app/code and create only etc and Observer

Comment: If you have any existing module then you can create `events.xml` and `ForceCustomerLoginObserver.php` file in that module. 
If you want to create new module than just create a simple module and then create `events.xml` and `ForceCustomerLoginObserver.php` file in that module. 
You will have to only update `Vendor/Module` name with you module name.

Comment: okay thanks, I will try it

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: yes when i click product so give this error 
Undefined variable: controller in
/app\/code\/Sm\/Magetheme\/Observer\/ForceCustomerLoginObserver.php on line 38",

Comment: Please use my updated answer. I just define `$controller` variable after `$actionName`

Comment: You will havr to change Vednor name and Module name in my code with your module name 
`Vendor\\Module\\Observer\\ForceCustomerLoginObserver` == `Sm\\Magetheme\\Observer\\ForceCustomerLoginObserver`

Comment: Ok it's working thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Override the layout **catalog_product_view.xml** and add a new custom block and phtml file.

Create a custom block file and add code for getting customer sessions, if the session exists continue otherwise redirect from it.

For adding custom block check that reference [Add custom block](https://magecomp.com/blog/add-block-add-cart-button-magento-2-product-page/) and for getting customer session check reference [Customer Session](http://www.blogtreat.com/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/).

Comment: sorry abhinay I can not get it, please explain

Comment: Override the layout and add your own block and phtml file inside that layout.

And Inside that block add a function that return current customer is login or not.

If the customer is logged in then he/she can able to access of product page otherwise redirect to another page with your custom message.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the requirement by creating a module with following steps:

**Step 1:** Create **registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/LoginProduct/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_LoginProduct',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:** Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/LoginProduct/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_LoginProduct" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Create **di.xml** under

> app/code/STech/LoginProduct/etc/frontend/di.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="STech_Plugin_Catalog_Controller_Product_View" sortOrder="10" type="STech\LoginProduct\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product\View"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 4:** Create **View.php** under

> app/code/STech/LoginProduct/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\LoginProduct\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product;

class View
{
    protected $customerSession;

    protected $_urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ){
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedin()) {
            $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
            $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Now run the below commands:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Thats it!